# Stop Windows 11 restoring windows on connecting a USB dock

Tags: windows-11, window-manager

Whenever I connect my Windows 11 computer to a USB based dock (Specifically two different versions of the Humanscale M/Connect dock) all windows that I have minimized are restored to their opened or maximized state. I cannot find any setting to stop Windows from doing this and having to re-minimize windows multiple times each and every day is getting really tiresome. Is there a way to fix this?